# Как посчитать средние значения по категориям в R?

Tags: r

Мне нужно создать таблицу с дискриптивной статистикой. Есть данные из эксперимента с двумя зависимые переменные: аккуратностью (acc) и временем реакции (rt). Независимые переменные - категориальные. Датасет выглядит следующим образом (116*5):

```
acc      rt         clause preference language_status
89.55286 995.7144   ORC    dispref    monoR
85.14141 878.4771   ORC    pref       bi
...
```

Вот пример того, что я хочу получить на выходе: средние значения двух переменных для каждой катогории.

```
acc_mean_ORC acc_mean_SRC  acc_mean_pref  acc_mean_dispref rt_mean_ORC rt_mean_SRC rt_mean_pref rt_mean_dispref
89.5         99.5 85.      87.4           95.6             995         800    
 900    700
```

Только у меня еще есть 3 группы языка (language_status), который мне тоже хочется иметь в той же таблице. Я не знаю, позволяют ли средства R совместить всё в одной таблице, но мой научный руководитель хочет, чтобы данные в дипломе выглядели именно так. Я делала линейную регрессию в R, поэтому хотела сделать таблице здесь же. 
Прикладываю версию таблицы на бумаге, которую представляю себе. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21982987/4827341

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin вопрос был, как сделать сводную таблицу. Та ссылка, которой Вы поделились, не отвечает на мой вопрос.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin хотя я была не права. Но всё же я не понимаю, как теперь из полученной агрегированной таблицы сделать эстетически приемлемую.

Comment: получаете значения, формируете из них таблицу. в чём проблема-то?

Answer (score 1):

Я не знаю, если возможно генирировать сводную таблицу, как показано на бумаге. Есть такой подход. Сначала заргузите `dplyr`. Затем, сгруппировывайте по именам и суммируете по среднему значению

```
df_langclause <- df %>% group_by(language_status, clause) %>% summarise(mean_acc=mean(acc), mean_rt=mean(rt))

df_langpref <- df %>% group_by(language_status, preference) %>% summarise(mean_acc=mean(acc), mean_rt=mean(rt))
```

Дальше, соедините эти таблицы по `language_status`

```
summary_table <- inner_join(df_langclause, df_langpref, by = "language_status")
```

Есть ещё полезная библиотека для визуализации таблиц данных, `kableExtra`. Посмотрите, если хотите визуализацию.

```
summary_table %>% kable() %>% kable_styling()
```